# Outlook Anywhere Credentials on SBS08

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, outlook-anywhere

I'm running SBS08 and have some clients using Outlook Anywhere (combination of Outlook 2003/2007) to access the Exchange Server.

The users are currently prompted for their domain usernames/password every time they start up Outlook (there is no "Save this password" prompt). Is there a way to configure the server or clients so that the user credentials are somehow cached/remembered?

Answer (score 1):

1. The user must be logged into the PC with an Active Directory account
2. The primary mailbox that they are accessing must be the same one as the account they are logged in as.

If both of the above are not true, then you will have to enter a password to access Outlook. However, if the above is true and you still have problems, more issues may be at play.

Comment: Outlook Anywhere is RPC over HTTP. See my answer as to how you can save the password.

Comment: I know Outlook Anywhere is RPC over HTTP, but in my experience the user you log in as and the mailbox you attempt to connect to will cause this symptom of the credentials being asked for.

Comment: The question isn't why this happens, it's "Is there a way to configure the server or clients so that the user credentials are somehow cached/remembered?". I don't see where you answered that question.

Comment: Ah ha. I see the nuance now. I suppose I looked at the problem a bit deeper. Instead of answering how to cache credentials, I tried to address why the authentication dialog box popped up in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. The computers which I am running Outlook Anywhere are not connected to the domain.

Comment: If your PCs were on the domain and users were logging in via domain credentials, then Basic or NTLM credentials would not matter and Outlook would open without asking for credentials. However, I now realize that my answer isn't quite addressing your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Use NTLM authentication then edit [this](http://bytesolutions.com/Support/Knowledgebase/KB_Viewer/smid/622/ArticleID/7/reftab/195/t/How-to-get-Windows-to-save-password-for-Outlook-Anywhere.aspx) registry value. Users can then save the password.

Comment: NTLM authentication should be avoided because it has the potential to expose passwords.